# How to run Athena | Coq | Isabelle codes remotely?

Tags: computer-science, background-process, coq, isabelle

I' ve been creating a Web IDE (WIDE) for theorem proving in Computer Science. You may know, there are 3 most common proof assitants which names Athena, Isabelle and Coq. Most of computer scientist might forget their syntax, scopes etc. My Web IDE works with drag and drop desing and examples. You can edit and write additional code on it, you can download it, you can share it, you can save it etc. It has also own parser. So far everything is OK. Watch out! Here is my question: How can I run the users' codes and get the result (especially for Athena http://proofcentral.org/) when user would like to run their code on my Web IDE. Actually, I can do this via mouse_event (user32) and other ones with pinvoke(platform invoke). My program sends the codes via Web to running PC(not server. Because server hasn't screen, so program won't know click to where), then the PC get the codes. Then the program click to "emacs" icon. After a few seconds(for openning and uploading dlls of Athena), the program paste that Athena codes into emacs shell. Emacs run that codes and return the result. After that the program select, copy and return the result to Web IDE. However this is a freaky and tricky way. I would like to do best way.
Thanks for your attention. Best

Comment: What do you mean "via web"? Also, do you really think that Athena runs only within emacs?

Comment: Actually, it doesn' t matter. Somehow I get the user' s code. But If you wonder it, I' ve written another program (and if you wonder tech: WEB.API) on PC for catch the code(you know, just a string) and return the result. Yes, as I mentioned before, "uploading dlls of Athena". That means that we have already Athena' s library and environment. Pls see the factorial example: http://prntscr.com/7ieahu

Answer (score 3):

I can only give an partial answer for **Isabelle**:

Isabelle itself is implemented in Standard ML, but for communicating with the external world, it uses a protocol called *PIDE* (= *Prover IDE*). The reference implementation of PIDE is bundled with Isabelle and written in Scala, so it can be used with any JVM language. The primary application of PIDE is *Isabelle/jEdit*, which uses the jEdit editor to build an IDE for Isabelle, including markup, continuous checking, ...

There are also other IDEs like [*Isabelle/Eclipse*](https://andriusvelykis.github.io/isabelle-eclipse/) and [*Clide*](https://github.com/martinring/clide2) (web-based). For your use case, Clide appears to be highly relevant.

If you want to know more about the inner workings of PIDE, you can consult the relevant papers by Wenzel, for example [*Asynchronous User Interaction and Tool Integration in Isabelle/PIDE*](http://www4.in.tum.de/~wenzelm/papers/itp-pide.pdf) and [*Isabelle as Document-oriented Proof Assistant*](http://www4.in.tum.de/~wenzelm/papers/isabelle-doc.pdf).

Now, finally, shameless plug: Since the question of how to interact with Isabelle as an external program comes up every now and then, I've packaged PIDE with some additional utilities as [*libisabelle*](https://github.com/larsrh/libisabelle). It includes an example of a very simple ping/pong interaction with the prover.

Comment: Hey Lars, I didn' t hear the Clide before. Thanks for your great answer!  However the Isabelle is our next stage. Cuz my supervisor works on Athena (Mr Vargun' s PhD thesis: http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~musser/gsd/athena/cct-thesis.pdf) with Konstantine Arkoudas and David Musser.

Comment: Just as a warning: It is not safe to expose an Isabelle instance to untrusted users (at least without further measures), as Isabelle documents may contain ML code and hence can execute arbitrary code.