# Calling Isabelle from external software (Java, Scheme)

Tags: java, scheme, isabelle

Is it possible to call Isabelle from external programms (Java, Scheme/Guile)? I have not managed to find documentation about API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar questions come up every now and then, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40848265/4776939) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30905122/4776939). None of them talks about Java or Scheme though, so here's a slightly adapted answer for the "Java" part.

### Calling Isabelle from Java

Isabelle itself has no "API" that can be called from external tools. The general philosophy is that applications should live inside Isabelle or the [Archive of Formal Proofs](https://www.isa-afp.org/). Most of the time, this means your applications needs to be implemented in Isabelle/ML.

However, if you want to use Isabelle *as an external tool*, you have to play some tricks. I have bundled up these tricks as a Scala library ([libisabelle](https://github.com/larsrh/libisabelle)). An overview of how this works is given in [a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.01539).

libisabelle itself is available as a stand-alone library including some basic documentation that should allow you to get started. See [the repository](https://github.com/larsrh/libisabelle) for more details. In essence, it allows you to

- manage Isabelle installations from within Scala (download, unpacking)
- abstract over different Isabelle versions (currently supported: 2016 and 2016-1)
- lifecycle management of an Isabelle session (building, starting, stopping)
- treat Isabelle/ML functions as Scala functions
- goodies like Isabelle term syntax in Scala (`term"$n > 0 --> ($b & ${HOLogic.True})"`)

There is no built-in routine to set up a goal state and apply some proof steps, but the necessary infrastructure is all there.

libisabelle is implemented in Scala, but there is a Java API that you can use, too. I know of one user who successfully uses that one. You can have a look at [an example](https://github.com/larsrh/libisabelle/blob/v0.8.0/modules/examples/src/main/java/edu/tum/cs/isabelle/examples/Hello_PIDE.java) in the repository.